# How to do CosmosDB JOIN to get an array of Column values

Tags: join, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have following data in cosmosDb

```
[
 { 
   accountId : "12453"
   tag : "abc"
 },
 {
   accountId : "12453"
   tag : "bcd"
 },
 { 
   accountId : "34567"
   tag : "qwe"
 },
 {
   accountId : "34567"
   tag : "xcx"
 }
]
```

And desired output is something like this

```
[
 {
   accountId : "123453"
   tag : {
       "abc",
       "bcd"
  },
  {
   accountId : "34567"
   tag : {
       "qwe",
       "xcx"
   }
  ]
```

I tried Join, array and group by in multiple ways but didn't work.

Below query gives similar output but rather than count I am looking for an array of tags

```
  select c.accountId, count(c.tag) from c where c.accountId = "12453" group BY c.accountId
```

Also tried below query

```
 select c.accountId, ARRAY(select c.tag from c IN f where f.accountId = "12453") as tags FROM f
```

This doesn't return any tag values and I get below output but I need distinct accountId and when I try DISTINCT on accountId, it gives an error.

```
   [ 
     {
     accountId : "12,
     tag : []
     }
     ........
   ]
```

Can someone please help with correct query syntax

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As M0 B said, this is not supported. Cosmos DB can't combine arrays across documents. You need to handle this on your client side.